# Keep button pressed down through view controller switch

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I am currently creating a view which should appear when a user presses a button, and disappear as soon as they release a different button in the same place as the previous one. The only problem is that when the new view appears - when the view controller is switched - the new button appears deselected, despite it being set to selected and/or highlighted in its class's viewDidLoad method.

Code

```
override func viewDidLoad{
   seeBillButton.selected = true
   seeBillButton.highlighted = true
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you ever switch it to `.selected = false` anywhere in the view controller?

Comment: how are you dismissing the second view controller,  is the parent doing the dismissing?  Also,  try moving your method to viewWillAppear,  I have found that buttons tend to get reset after the point of viewdidload.  Finally, did you check that viewdidload is begin called again on the first controller,  the view may already be in memory and not be called, and the view controller 1 touch up outside event is being fired to deselect it

Comment: Aside from it being possible, is it the best user experience? I don't think it is very intuitive that users have to keep pressing a button that gets replaced/covered. Is there a reason this needs to be exactly like this?

Comment: I do not do that, Fennelouski. Knight0fDragon, the dismissing is done by the newly presented view controller, right when the user releases the button. All of what you said has been checked - no solution. I understand, R Menke, but the other option is to present a view in the current view controller, vanishing all other elements "in the background". I just need to get a button selected even though a user already has his/her finger in the "new" button's position. As it is right now they have to lift it and touch again.